# Jira: Any way to define default issues to add to new project?

Tags: jira, issue-tracking

Is anyone aware of a way to define a set of default issues, which can then be attached to a project type definition so that each time a project of this type is created, it comes with these issues?

All of our projects have issues like 'create wireframes','set up local environment' etc. and I'm looking for a quick way to automate this part of project setup.

I have full admin access and I can't see anything in the issue or project setup that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a set of issues in an empty project and export them?

You can use that set and import it into your new project to start with.

Comment: This sounds promising, I'll try it out and see how I get on, thanks.